# Ethereum JSON keystore file leaked - security?

Tags: private-key, keystore

If the JSON keystore file has been leaked but the password has not, can the attacker with the keystore file do anything?

Assume the password is 20 or more characters long and not used in any other place.

Comment: I think this is not different from a simpler scenario such as ``a guy knows your email address but not your password``. Same problems/solutions apply.

Comment: It is not that bad if you have a good password, upper case, lower case, numbers, digits. But I'll move the funds when possible. @FlorianCastelain since you can try to brute force the file offline it is a bit different than accessing an online account.